# Is it possible to modify iTunes tracks using Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, itunes, scripting-bridge

The question is in the title :) I'm playing a bit with Objective-C and Scripting Bridge. I know it is possible to get information (readonly) from iTunes, but i see nowhere a way to modify a track, for exemple change its name. Is it possible with this or another technology ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, from the Scripting Library in AppleScript Editor, I can see that a `file_track` inherits from `item` and an `item` has the read-write property `name`.  So you should be able to set it just as easily as you can read it.

Edit:  Actually, almost every piece of meta-data is part of `track` (of which `file_track` inherits aswell) and most are read-write properties...

[Doug Adams](http://dougscripts.com) has one [such script](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=songtitlearticles) which can change titles from song in iTunes.  Maybe have a look at it?

As for setting it via Objective-C, perhaps [this documention](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104-CH4-DontLinkElementID_14) can help you.

Exerpt from the website:

> ***Listing 2-3  Setting the locked property of Finder items***
>
> ```
> int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) { 
>    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
>    FinderApplication *theFinder = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier: @"com.apple.finder"]; 
>    SBElementArray *trashItems = [[theFinder trash] items]; 
>    if ([trashItems count] > 0) { 
>        for (FinderItem *item in trashItems) { 
>            if ([item locked]==YES) 
>                [item setLocked:NO];          // <<<-- Setting the property
>        } 
>    } 
>    [pool drain]; 
>    return 0; 
> }
> ```

---

Have you tried:

```
iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"]; 
[[iTunes currentTrack] setName:@"The New Song Title"]);
```

Comment: Okay thanks, i'm gonna look at that. I got confused because of the keyword copy with property declaration in the iTunes.h file. In fact it will work, hope so !

Comment: Wow okay that's awesome :) i'm really really really new to this though

Comment: note: since currentTrack and name are properties you can use the property syntax:

    iTunes.currentTrack.name = @"The New Song Title";